# Create a JSON using Custom metadata type

Tags: apex, json, callout, custom-metadata

I have a custom metadata which store some parameters which I need to pass in Post callout.I have stotred the Options in below JSON in that custom metadata

```
{
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "options": {
    "validateRegex": true,
    "validateMx": true,
    "validateTypo": true,
    "validateDisposable": true,
    "validateSMTP": false
  }
}
```

[image]
I have a LWC which pass email from front end to back end. But I want to know, How can I add that email to a JSON in above with custom metadata and create a http request body with that?
Is it a possible functionality in apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively easily achieved by using an Apex class/inner class to define the structure of the JSON.

```
public class EmailOptions {

    public static String email;
    public static EmailOptionAttributes options;

    public class EmailOptionAttributes {
        public static Boolean validateRegex;
        public static Boolean validateMx;
        public static Boolean validateType;
        public static Boolean validateDisposable;
        public static Boolean validateSMTP;
    }

}
```

In your Apex you can then create an instance of this based on your Custom Metadata Type and then use the [JSON.serialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize) function to convert the object into a JSON string.

Comment: Thank you Callum MacErlich, Will try and get back to this.

Comment: @Buhuni how did you get along with this? Did it work for you?

Comment: Thank you for that. Thanks once again.